# zsh: command not found: hiptest-publisher

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm using hiptest-publisher in order to push test results on the cucumber studio platform. The tests run and pass.
I installed Ruby and then ran `gem install hiptest-publisher`.

When I try to run this command to push the test execution result back to Cucumber Studio:

```
hiptest-publisher --config-file=<path> --push="target/cucumber.json" --push-format=cucumber-json --test-run-id=123
```

I receive this error:

[image]

Any advice to solve this problem is welcome.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's like with **every** command (untelated to cucumber or ruby): Either provide an explicit path, or put the directory where the command is located into your `path` array (and make sure that it is executable).

Comment: BTW, I took the liberty to edit your tags so that they are more meaningful to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
How did I solve it?

**Step 1**

```
$ gem environment
```

Will tell you the EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY.

**Step 2**

Put whatever that value is in your PATH in your .bashrc or other shell config file.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/bin"
```

Thank you!